# angular-google-maps map pin moves along with map

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-google-maps

I have following code but the problem is that the pin that points the address is not fixed if the map is moved the pin remains at the same position instead of staying at where it was pinned.

Controller

```
$scope.map = {
                        center: {
                            latitude: location.lat,
                            longitude: location.long
                        },
                        zoom: 17,
                        formattedAddress: location.formatted_address
                    }
```

View

```
<ui-gmap-google-map
                class="col-md-12"
                center="map.center"
                zoom="map.zoom"
                ng-cloak>
            <ui-gmap-marker coords="map.center" idkey="1" ng-cloak>
                <ui-gmap-window>
                    <p>{{map.formattedAddress}}</p>
                </ui-gmap-window>
            </ui-gmap-marker>

        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 10):

Marker is set to be in center of te map

```
<ui-gmap-marker coords="map.center" idkey="1" ng-cloak>
```

It is also important when You create the map not to make map centre and marker coords the same object reference.

```
var coords = {lat: x, lng : x}
map.center = coords
marker.coords = coords
```

Because this will also make the marker move.
Use

```
marker.coords = Object.create(coords)
```

Comment: In my case I was using the same instance of coords. Creating a new reference fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This is all correct; see the bottom of this thread. https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/498

Comment: This is a perfect explain and solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where the map is binded to 1 coords property, where the map is to be centered at. 
Then I have a marker which I wanted to be placed at that same location.

When you moved the map, the binded 'ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center"' property changed, and also the marker was binded to that same map.center property so it moved along with it.

I solved it by have two separate coords objects. One for the initial map center and one for the marker. Then dragging one won't affect the other.

(In my situation, I wish you could omit the 'ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center"'  and just depend on the markers 'fit' property to fit all the markers smartly without caring about where to center the map. Think there is a way to do it with 'bounds' property but would be kinda looping through all markers and figure out the top-left to bottom-right largest lat/long bounds).

Comment: How is this any different then the above answer?

Comment: Hey @Nick , thought I answered first (April 21st vs June 1st) so its not like I answered thinking I was just re-hashing and copying the above post which is now higher rated.

Comment: Yeah no worries, but both posts are saying the same thing.